# How to find missing side for this isosceles triangle problem?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

There's a chance this problem from my instructor might be flawed. Our guesses for $X$ are $2.3$ and $1.5$. The symbol that looks like $2.2$ is actually a ??. It is unknown whether our instructor wants us to find the ??.

[image]

Comment: How did you arrive at your "guesses" for $x$? And what makes you think the problem is "flawed"?

Comment: The area of the triangle is $\frac{x\cdot x\cdot \sin(A)}{2}$ it is also $\frac{x\cdot 1\cdot \sin(2A)}{2}$. Therefore, $x\sin(A)=\sin(2A)$. Since $\sin(2A)=2\sin(A)\cos(A)$, we get that $x=2\cos(A)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)$. Roughly $1.62$.

Comment: Question seems fine. You could try the law of cosines to find x (once you've determined the ?? side lengths). Alternatively, you could observe that the larger triangle is isosceles and drop an altitude down, giving you a right triangle with base $1/2$ and hypotenuse $x$.

Comment: This problem ... pure gold. :-)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Note that the triangles ABD and CBD are isosceles; the triangles ABC and BCD are similar. Therefore,

$$AC = x = 1+ \frac1x \implies x^2-x-1=0$$

which yields $x = \frac12(1+\sqrt5)$.

Comment: It's worth noting that $x = \overline{AC}:\overline{AD} = \overline{AD}:\overline{DC}$, which reduces it to a string cutting problem (e.g. cut a string in two such that the ratio of the original length to the longest piece is the same as the ratio of the longer piece to that of the shorter piece.). :-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is simply to recognize that $\dfrac{1/2}{x} = \cos(72\;$degrees).
googling $\cos(72\;$degrees), you can easily find its expression by radicals.

Answer (score 0):

Did you recognize that the given triangle is identical to the inner triangle in a regular pentagon?[image]